Pytest ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' despite working in Docker environment
I'm encountering an issue where pytest fails to run tests in my local development environment due to a ModuleNotFoundError, specifically stating that there is "No module named 'app'". However, my backend application runs perfectly fine within a Docker container, and the app module is recognized without any issues in that environment.
Project Structure:
project-root/
├── app/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── setup/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data/
│   │   ├── technology/
│   │   │   ├── enums/
│   │   │        ├── __init__.py
│   │   │        ├── technology_type_enum.py
│   ├── tests/
│   │   ├── data/
│   │   │        ├── __init__.py
│   │   │        ├── test_import.py
│   │   ├── conftest.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── CHANGELOG.md

conftest.py:
from config import config
from setup import create_app, db
import os
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    os.environ['ENV'] = 'test'
    app = create_app(config.SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED)
    yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
        yield client

test_import.py:
def test_import():
    try:
        from data.technology.enums import TechnologyTypeEnum
        assert True
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        assert False, "Import failed"

Error Message:
ERROR app/tests - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.technology'

What I’ve Tried:

PYTHONPATH Adjustments:

I set PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)/app and PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) before running pytest, but neither resolved the issue.

I also created a pytest.ini file in the root directory to specify the pythonpath, but it didn’t resolve the issues either:
[pytest]
pythonpath = app

[pytest]
pythonpath = absolute/path/to/project/app




Docker Environment:

The backend runs without issues inside a Docker container. The app module is correctly recognized, and everything works as expected.


Running pytest in Docker:

I also tried running pytest inside the Docker container to ensure consistency with the environment where the backend works correctly. Unfortunately, I encountered the same ModuleNotFoundError for the app module even within the Docker environment.


Path Modifications:

I tried modifying sys.path directly in conftest.py to include the project root directory, but this also didn’t resolve the issue.



Question:
Why does pytest fail to recognize the app module both locally and in Docker, when the backend runs perfectly fine in Docker? How can I configure my environment to allow pytest to recognize the app module, or what might I be missing in my setup?
Any guidance on resolving this discrepancy between the working backend and the failing pytest would be greatly appreciated.

The problem you are facing is the result of an incorrect class import in test_import.py.The test file attempts to import data directly rather than using app.data.
I would take the following approach:
In the test_import.py instead of using from data.technology.enums import TechnologyTypeEnum to import TechnologyTypeEnum , use
from app.data.technology.enums.technology_type_enum import TechnologyTypeEnum.
This is the correct way to import TechnologyTypeEnum as per your code base setup
.After doing this change when you will rerun
pytest test app/tests/data/test_import.py

This should fix the error.
For better understanding i am attaching two images file below , first one is showing the error that you faced and second one demonstrates the positive results after implementing the changes.
Error Encountered
Successfull Outcome

The question asks: "Why does pytest fail to recognize the app module both locally and in Docker, when the backend runs perfectly fine in Docker? How can I configure my environment to allow pytest to recognize the app module, or what might I be missing in my setup?"
